# Installing OpenCV on Raspberry Pi using package

Tags: c++, opencv, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am trying to install OpenCV in a correct way on my raspberry pi in order to stitch images together. After trying to compile from the source on github (very long on raspberry) and having issues finding some libraries used by stitcher.hpp (namely gpu.hpp and opencv_modules.hpp), I tried the package way.

I installed the package libopencv-dev with the version 2.4.1+dfsg-0exp2rpi2 but it was not successful as I could not find opencv_modules.hpp in opencv2 directory as well as gpu.hpp.

Does anyone have an idea why neither the package nor the compilation give a correct set of libraries for OpenCV2? Do you have a good install process? After few days looking around on the Internet I could not find a way.

Thank you

Comment: I finally found a way to have a working OpenCV library. I first prepare the compilation, generating the build, but not starting the compiling. Then I grouped in a folder opencv2 to be placed in the /usr/include folder of your RPi all the modules library headers (one folder by module with .hpp file and opencv.hpp and opencv_modules.hpp in the root folder). Then I installed the package from Nolaan (see http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=33&t=81503&start=25) that place all the source files. Nota: A little crappy way, and only available for version 2.4.10.

Answer (score 3):

I had similar challenges for python based OpenCV- and eventually was able to compile openCV and get mine working.  For my next pi, I tried a more simple approach, with success for python based cv2 code.

Here's my short answer - maybe it will help:
`sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev python-opencv`

From a fresh Raspbian I usually do/install the following first, as my work seems to depend on some of these libraries, so here's the full process I use to get OpenCV going:

`sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade`

`sudo apt-get -y install build-essential cmake cmake-curses-gui pkg-config libpng12-0 libpng12-dev libpng++-dev libpng3 libpnglite-dev zlib1g-dbg zlib1g zlib1g-dev pngtools libtiff4-dev libtiff4 libtiffxx0c2 libtiff-tools libeigen3-dev`

`sudo apt-get -y install libjpeg8 libjpeg8-dev libjpeg8-dbg libjpeg-progs ffmpeg libavcodec-dev libavcodec53 libavformat53 libavformat-dev libgstreamer0.10-0-dbg libgstreamer0.10-0 libgstreamer0.10-dev libxine1-ffmpeg libxine-dev libxine1-bin libunicap2 libunicap2-dev swig libv4l-0 libv4l-dev python-numpy libpython2.6 python-dev python2.6-dev libgtk2.0-dev`

`sudo apt-get install libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev`

Then finally 
`sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev python-opencv`

Comment: I got stuck on the missing headers after installing the libopencv_2.4.10.deb by Nolaan but then "sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev" solved the thing (I am using C++).

Comment: Awesome..!! You saved a lot of  my time!!